# Simulate multivariate outliers

Tags: multivariate-analysis, outliers, diagnostic, multivariate-regression

Considering a multivariate linear model $\boldsymbol{Y = XB + E}$, where $\boldsymbol{Y, X, B}$ and $\boldsymbol{E}$ have dimension $n \times m$, $n \times p$, $p \times m$ and $n \times m$, respectively.

I read in [this](https://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2019/03/27/simulate-multivariate-outliers.html) page about outliers only in $\boldsymbol{Y}$, i.e. without considering $\boldsymbol{X}$.

However, I'd like to simulate outliers for $\boldsymbol{Y}$ considering the pair $(\boldsymbol{Y, X})$ to regression problem.

Comment: Do you know the distribution of $E$?

Comment: Yes, multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: Then try simulating $E$ from the appropriate multivariate Normal, add some outliers to it, and calculate $Y_{sim}=X\beta+E_{sim}$ for whatever $X$ you are interested in simulating $Y$ for.   How you add those outliers is likely to be the meat of whatever answer you accept!

Comment: I can't use a similar approach, because I need a methodology to build outliers. I will use in my thesis.